# Scala actor memory leaks, are they as bad as It was or improving?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

I am currently studding Scala 2.8 using Programming in Scala 2nd edition.

But I am beginning to get really concerned about posts like this [Clojure vs Scala](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/b18f9006c068f0a0)

Is Scala this bad about memory leaks, this is not the first info I heard about issues with actors and memory leaks.

Is it that bad? are new versions fixing it in reasonable time? Is Akka going to solve all of it if or when if it's merged?

Because seeing big issues with **one of scala biggest** strong points (at least for me Erlang like actors are one of the major candies of the lang) is really a major drawback if they are not being able to fix them and improve on top of it.

Comment: Linked is an interesting comment on the mailing list thread, [Should Scala's native actors library be marked obsolete](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Should-Scala-s-native-actors-library-be-marked-obsolete-tp3219212p3221456.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know of people using huge numbers of actors, so I'm pretty sure memory leaks are not widespread.

Did Scala Actors have memory leaks back in 2009 (Scala 2.7.x)? Yes, they did. For example, [SI-1801](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1801) and [SI-1948](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1948).

Right now, there are three tickets open on memory leaks that I could find: [SI-3467](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3467),[SI-3920](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3920) and [SI-3921](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3921).

I do take issue with one comment you made, however:

> one of scala biggest strong points (at least for me Erlang like actors
>   are one of the major candies of the lang)

Actors are **NOT** part of the language! They are a library! That is the whole point of Scala, it is the very meaning of "scalable" from which the name Scala came: that you can add stuff like this *through libraries*.

There are, right now, *four* different actor implementations in Scala: main library, Scalaz, Lift and Akka. There's absolutely *no* reason for you to tie yourself to the standard library one. In fact, one of the problems with the actors in the main library is that they were written more to prove that one could do it than to solve real problems.

If you want to use actors, use Akka. You can use it *right now*. Hell, you can even use it with Java, if you're into syntactic masochism. Akka is a superb library, which goes far beyond simply providing actors, and into providing all the supporting tool to make them useful (like supervisors and load balancers), plus other tools to fully support concurrency, like Agents (Clojure-style), STM (Multiverse-based), integration with Spring, Camel, AMQP, etc.

Scala's strength is making it possible to seemingly extend it through libraries. If you limit yourself to what's on the standard library, you are throwing that away.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right my statement was not correct.

Answer (score 3):

You should try Akka. It's really robust, lightweight and tunable. For instance, you can [bound mailbox sizes](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.2-RC6/scala/dispatchers.html#making-the-actor-mailbox-bounded) (and choose what to do when mailboxes are full).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Scala internals much, but I would guess that Scala's actors implementation is queuing every message without limit.

If the actors don't pull from the queue fast enough, the queue grows and consumes memory.

I guess a less memory angry implementation would limit the number of queued messages at once, and thus consume less memory (but would also block message senders while the queue is full).